# Boost. Link dependency with short name

Tags: gcc, boost, solaris, ldd

I'am trying build boost 1.69 on Solaris 11.3 with gcc 4.8.2.
Then build is complete i'am see (with ldd libname.so) that linker using relative path in dynamic section tag NEEDED 
bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_atomic.so.1.69.0
It is not good. I want to linker use only libname without any path (absolute or relative).
How i can set short name link?

So: outut ldd from solaris and ldd from RHEL 6

**Solaris**

ldd libboost_thread.so.1.69.0

```
    **bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_system.so.1.69.0** =>        bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_system.so.1.69.0
```

.........

**linux**

ldd libboost_thread.so.1.69.0

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00ba6000)
    **libboost_system.so.1.69.0** => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.69.0 (0x00a53000)
```

........

Why on Solaris boost building with using crasy path in dependency name, but on Linux - it normal - only libname without any path. How i can say to b2 or other tool to use only short dependency name?

Comment: What does `elfdump -d libboost_thread.so.1.69.0` show on Solaris?  Is it actually part of the NEEDED entry or from the RPATH?

Comment: [0]  NEEDED          0x3c13   bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_system.so.1.69.0
      [1]  NEEDED          0x3b63   librt.so.1
      [2]  NEEDED          0x3b77   libstdc++.so.6
      [3]  NEEDED          0x3c7a   libm.so.2
      [4]  NEEDED          0x3bbb   libgcc_s.so.1
      [5]  NEEDED          0x3bd1   libpthread.so.1
      [6]  NEEDED          0x3bf3   libc.so.1

On [0] linker used relative path but on other dependencies use only name (that i need). WHY?

Answer (score 0):

The Solaris linker is simply recording what it was told - it appears the command to link the software passed `bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_system.so.1.69.0` to the linker, instead of the normal `-Lbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/ -lboost_system`.  You'll have to look into the build scripts/Makefiles to determine why it's doing that.